# Generate a unique key for React while using LodashFP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am trying to use Lodash's map method to render a list of components in React, but the key that is generated is consistently the same because of the way it's returned. Is there any sort of work around for this?

```
{map((item) => (<Item {...item} key={item.id} />), items}
```

Comment: You're using this [`_.map(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map), right?

Comment: I am using [Lodash FP](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide), so the option to define an index as a second parameter isn't available. Using [Capping](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#convert) didn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use index number as a key. 
[here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) is the blog why?

The best way I found is this `btoa(Math.random()).substring(0, 12)`
btoa is natively supported in JS.

```js
   console.log(btoa(Math.random()).substring(0, 12))
```

key={btoa(Math.random()).substring(0, 12)}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on loadashFP already you could simply use [**`_.uniqueId`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqueId) with a prefix:

```
_.uniqueId('KEY_');  // KEY_1
_.uniqueId('KEY_');  // KEY_2 etc ...
```

In your case:

```
{map((item) => (<Item {...item} key={_.uniqueId('KEY_')} />), items}
```